# C code - Why the output returned unexpected value in my code?

Tags: c

I am a  C starter and just learned the basis of programming. When I practiced coding, I noticed something weird about the unexpected output that I don't know the reasons for it and can't even describe what the problem is.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main()
{
  int numberEntered = 0;
  int index = 0;
  char input[32];
  int TotalNum = 0;
  int x = 1;
  int array[x];

  printf("Please enter the size of the array: ");
  fgets(input,32,stdin);
  x = atoi(input);

  for(index =0; index < x; index++)
  {
      printf("\nPlease enter your number:");
      fgets(input,32,stdin);

      numberEntered = atoi(input);
      printf("The number you entered is : %d\n",numberEntered);


      array[index] = numberEntered;

      TotalNum ++;
   }

  for(index = 0; index < TotalNum; index++)
  {
      printf("array[%d] = %d\n",index,array[index]);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

While user input an x = 15; And users then enter numbers from 1 to 15;
The output was:

```
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
array[2] = 3
array[3] = 4
array[4] = 5
array[5] = 6
array[6] = 7
array[7] = 668977
array[8] = 9
array[9] = 10
array[10] = 11
array[11] = 12
array[12] = 13
array[13] = 14
array[14] = 15
```

I originally expect that the array[7] should give me an output of array[7] = 8, since the number "8" is what the users typed. However, it changed to random numbers. I would like to know the reason for that.

Comment: `int x = 1; int array[x];`-- How big is your array when you create it? Changing `x` later won't make your array grow magically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int x = 1;
int array[x];

printf("Please enter the size of the array: ");
fgets(input,32,stdin);
x = atoi(input);
```

This line changes the value of `x`, but not the size of `array`. You can only give an array a size at the time it is declared. *)

Reorder this to the following:

```
printf("Please enter the size of the array: ");
fgets(input,32,stdin);
int x = atoi(input);
int array[x];
```

On a side note, `atoi()` isn't good for checking errors (which you should do on interactive input). Use `strtol()` instead, and make sure to read [the manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), so you make use of all possibilities to detect errors.

---

*) Note the feature you are using here is called *variable length array* (VLA), but the word "*variable*" only means that the size of the array isn't a *compile-time constant*.  It does **not** mean you can change the size once the array exists -- that would be a *dynamic array*, which you have to implement yourself in C (using `malloc()` and `realloc()`).

Also note VLAs, although very widespread, don't **have** to be supported, C11 makes them an optional feature. If you don't have VLAs available, you must use either a fixed size array large enough or allocate your array yourself using `malloc()`, in this case it would look like

```
int x = atoi(input);
int *array = malloc(x * sizeof *array);
```

Don't forget to check `array` for `NULL` when doing this and don't forget to `free(array);` when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Huh?

When you do this:

```
int x = 1;
int array[x];
```

You get a 1-element array called `array`. Changing the value of `x` later does not magically resize the array. Put the `array[x]` declaration *after* getting the proper value of `x`.

And add checks for the I/O calls, they can fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 1;
int array[x];
```

It limits the size of your array. Do not do like this.

Answer (score 0):

What?

```
  int x = 1;
  int array[x];

  // .....

  x = atoi(input);
```

Did you really expext that assigning a new value to the `x` variable will *resize* the already declared `array` variable???

No, you must declare the array when its size is known.

```
  int x;

  // .....

  x = atoi(input);

  int array[x];
```

Or, even better, allocate a new array from a heap, esp. when `x` is going to get *big* value some day...

```
  int arraylength;

  // .....

  arraylength = atoi(input);

  if (arraylength > 0)     // sanity check
  {
      int* array = malloc (arraylength * sizeof(int));
      if (array != NULL)   // allocation succeeded
      {
          // use array[i]...

          // and relese the array when no longer needed
          free (array);
      }
  }
```